# MIM ratio in electronics?

Tags: capacitor

I am working at a semiconductor company and we have some issues at the fabrication level.

I see an issue regarding the MIM ratio of a certain data.

What is this MIM Ratio? Is this a ratio of capacitor? Area of the metal of the capacitor?

Comment: Seriously?  Your question makes no sense at all.  You are an employee of this semiconductor company and responsible for some fabrication issue but you don't even know the definition of this?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I will not asking this question if I knew it. Also I am not working on the fabrication side but I work on the silicon itself so fabrication is not really my area. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MIM ratio, without context, is likely the area of the capacitor that is required for the mechanical step of polishing the MIM1 metal before the oxide deposition and MIM2.  Due to the fact that this step is often mechanical, you need a minimum size in some dimension to be sure that the tool doesn't eat into the other metal.

This should never actually be an issue as you'll catch it with Calibre during wafer assembly.

Comment: Thanks man. I think I am getting the idea. I just read some idea about this MIM. The issue we are encountering is that one customer is having some issue on our part and base on the history of this product, the issue only encountered on a certain fab wafer. We are investigating why this only occur on this certain wafer and analyzing the WAT data we found some shift on the MIM ratio for this wafer compared with the other wafer.